# Npgsql returns the content of an interval field as a .net string object

Tags: postgresql, mono, sqldatatypes, npgsql

I am currently struggling with a strange issue with my Npgsql driver: I would like to fetch interval values from a table in my database (PostgreSQL 9.3-3.1.2) for some calculations on the client side, but when I get it returned in a field of an IDataReader object, it's a System.String instead. Why? The docs say it shall be a System.TimeSpan object!

BTW, I am using the Npgsql driver contained in the openSuSE package mono-data-postgresql-3.12.1-6.9.x86_64. Shall I update it?

Thank you for any useful hints!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what version of Npgsql you get in that package, but there's a very good chance it's extremely outdated. The preferred way to get Npgsql (and most other .NET packages) is via nuget, where you can install the latest (3.0.3), this should resolve your issue.

Comment: That might be the problem: I can't figure out what driver version is actually in the package. gacutil shows 2.0.0 and 4.0.0, which doesn't sound very logical.

Comment: The best thing to do is remove that package entirely and use Nuget. GAC installations are pretty much a thing of the past in .NET.

Comment: OK, thank you for your hint. I've just installed Npgsql 3.0.4 via NuGet, but unfortunately, I've run into a much more serious issue: Many queries stoped working altogether due to an InvalidOperationException. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131285/npgsql-on-mono-an-operation-is-already-in-progress/34339385#34339385